# Data in Form not Emailed - MvcMailer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email, mvcmailer

I am trying to send the contents of a form with MvcMailer in my MVC 3 web application. The email sends, but it does not populate with the data from the form.

Here is the view of my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div id="section_1" class="section"> 
<p style="color:#e93738;display:none"></p> 

<img src="/Content/1.png" id="one" class="step" alt="Step 1"/>  
<h3>Personal Details of Student</h3> 
<p> 
<em>Please enter your personal details.</em><br /> 

</p> 
<br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantFirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantFirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantFirstName)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantLastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantLastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantLastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantBirthDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantBirthDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantBirthDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantCellphoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantCellphoneNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantCellphoneNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantEmailAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantEmailAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantEmailAddress)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantEmailAddress)
    </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantSuburb)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantSuburb)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantSuburb)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantCity)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicantCity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantCity)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationPostalCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicationPostalCode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationPostalCode)
    </div>

</div> 

<div id="section_2" class="section"> 
<img src="/Content/2.png" id="two" class="step" alt="Step 2"/>  
<h3>Parent Details</h3> 
<p> 
<em>Please enter your parent or guardian's details.</em><br /> 

</p> 

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentFirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentFirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentFirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentLastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentLastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentLastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentEmailAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentEmailAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentEmailAddress)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentPostalNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentPostalNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentPostalNumber)
    </div>

   <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentSuburb)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentSuburb)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentSuburb)
    </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentCity)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentCity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentCity)
    </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentPostalCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ParentPostalCode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentPostalCode)
    </div>

 </div> 
<a href='@Url.Action("SendApplication", "Home")'><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></a>
```

}

Here is part of my controller:

```
    private IApplicationMailer _applicationMailer = new ApplicationMailer();
    public IApplicationMailer ApplicationMailer
    {
        get { return _applicationMailer; }
        set { _applicationMailer = value; }
    }

    public ActionResult SendApplication(Application application)
    {
        ApplicationMailer.Application(application).Send();
         //Send() extension method: using Mvc.Mailer
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is my ApplicationMailer.cs:

```
    public virtual MailMessage Application(Application application)
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "Application"};

        mailMessage.To.Add("amecily@gmail.com");
        ViewBag.Data = "Debbie";
        ViewBag.FirstName = application.ApplicantFirstName;
        ViewBag.LastName = application.ApplicantLastName;
        PopulateBody(mailMessage, viewName: "Application");

        return mailMessage;
    }
```

My IApplicationMailer.cs:

```
public interface IApplicationMailer
{

    MailMessage Application(Application application);

}
```

And my Application.cshtml:

```
@model DFPProductions_Default.Models.Application

Hi @ViewBag.Data

A new application has been received:

@ViewBag.FirstName
@ViewBag.LastName
```

**EDIT:**

At the top of the view containing the form, I have:

```
@model DFPProductions_Default.Models.Application
```

And the Application.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DFPProductions_Default.Models
{
public class Application
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string ApplicantFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string ApplicantLastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Birth Date")]
    public DateTime ApplicantBirthDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Cellphone Number")]
    public string ApplicantCellphoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Postal Address")]
    public string PostalNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Suburb")]
    public string ApplicantSuburb { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string ApplicantCity { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    public string ApplicationPostalCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string ApplicantEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string ParentFirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string ParentLastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string ParentEmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Postal Address")]
    public string ParentPostalNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Suburb")]
    public string ParentSuburb { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string ParentCity {get; set;}
    [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    public string ParentPostalCode {get; set;}


   }
}
```

Comment: When you puta breakpoint to your application mailer, is the application filled with the correct data?

Comment: Can you add the source of your model object (Application class)? Obviously the modelbinding isn't working. Did you declare the model in your view? Something like: @model Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies here:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("SendApplication", "Home")'><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></a>
```

This won't work. Remove the  tags entirely so only the input tag remains. Then assign the action and controllername to the form like this:

```
@Html.BeginForm("SendApplication", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
```